# Display a list of subcategories (from specific Category) a post belongs to

Tags: customization

This code almost works, but it brings other categories that I do not want to display (minimun of 1, maximun of 3).
I have several categories and subcategories, that can be marked at the same post, but I just want to display subcategories that are marked and that are child of cat id=59 (example).

Code:

```
$taxonomy = 'category';

// get the term IDs assigned to post.
$post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
// separator between links
$separator = ', ';
$categories = get_the_category();
$parentid = $categories[0]->category_parent;
$parents = get_terms( 'category', array( 'parent' => 59 ) );
if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

    $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
    $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&child_of=' . $parentid . '&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
    $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );

    // display post categories
    echo  $terms;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the significance of category `59`? Do you only need the code to get children of exactly `59`?  Or is this value dynamic somehow?

Comment: Hi Jacob. Yes, I need to display inside the post, a list of the subcategories of the Category (id=59), sinse the post is marked (belongs to) in those subcategories.

Comment: the code above brings those subcategories, but if there are less than 3, it brings other categories and subcategories I don´t want to display.
Thats why I need to filter by cat 59 children only.

Comment: But do you only want to show children of `59` because that happens to be the category you want for this specific post? Or are you happy to hard-code `59` for all posts?

Comment: I want to show it in a box, for all posts, like the image above.

Comment: the names in yellow are the ones that I don´t want, because they are not from Cat 59, only the one in Green.

Comment: If I mark more subs from 59, than it displays the way I want, but I don´t know why.
Image #2 is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is that you've essentially mixed up what looks like 3 separate attempts at a solution. There's a lot of redundant code in there that's making it confusing to read. The actual line of code that's generating the output that you're seeing is this one:

```
$terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&child_of=' . $parentid . '&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
```

The problem is that here you've set `child_of=' . $parentid`, but `$parentid` isn't set to `59`, it's set to this:

```
$parentid = $categories[0]->category_parent;
```

There's no guarantee this will be the specific category that you want. The order of categories returned by `get_the_category()` is the order that the categories were added to the post. This isn't necessarily a category with `59` as its parent. If the first category doesn't have a parent, then this function will list all categories.

If you want:

- List categories for the current post.
- The categories should be children of category `59`.
- No more than 3 should be displayed.
- The categories should be separated by commas.

Then this is all the code you need:

```
$categories = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category', [ 'parent' => 59, 'number' => 3 ] );

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {
    $category_links = [];

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $category_links[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $category ) ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>';
    }

    echo implode( ', ', $category_links );
}
```

Comment: Works great!!!
Thanks a lot Jacob.
I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. If you mark the answer as accepted then other users can see that there's a solution to your question.

Comment: can you help with another thing?
In the same box, I want to display only 3 main categories, since they are marked for the post as well, also separated by commas.